# How to position button in the middle of an Iframe and load the Iframe only after pressing it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created the following test code in which I create an Iframe and a button and by using jquery, I load the contents of the Iframe only after the button is pressed.

The code can be run at: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GE2BVI7NSQ7N

However, now the button is below the Iframe and after I press it, it'll still be there.

What I want is to have the button be centered inside the Iframe, sort of like a "load this content" button, and after the button is pressed, then it disappears.

Basically, what I want is exactly what Itch.io is doing, like on this page: https://brackeysgames.itch.io/party-killer. There's an app inside an Iframe and a button to load the app. Once the button is pressed, it is removed and the app loads in its place.

How could I achieve that?

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var iframe = $("#myiFrame");
  iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
});
```

```css
.iframe-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Iframe test</h1>

<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="https://www.w3schools.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>

<button type="button">Load Iframe</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this

You need to position the button and hide it on load

I put it inside the same container as the iframe and made it position absolute

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  const $iframe = $("#myiFrame");
  const $but = $(this);
  $iframe.on("load",function() {
    $but.hide();
  })
  $iframe.attr("src", $iframe.data("src"));
});
```

```css
.iframe-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  position:absolute;
  top:40%;
  left:45%; /* perhaps use calc here */
  justify-content: center;
  z-index:999;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Iframe test</h1>

<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe id="myiFrame" data-src="https://www.w3schools.com" src="about:blank"></iframe>
  <button type="button">Load Iframe</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to anchor it to the Iframe? For instance, if the user has a mobile device then using their top 100px position for the button will be very different from a PC user's position for the same button.

Comment: That would be another question. I gave it 20% now  - but you need to position it relative to the container.

Comment: Got it. The "big change" that was needed was just putting the button inside the iframe-container div. Now that the div was the button's parent, the relative positioning was simple.